# How to Create multicell in fpdf

Tags: php, jquery, html, fpdf

Using the code below, PDF comes in disorderly manner and also overwrite each other. How to solve this and how to use MultiCell in fpdf?

```
<?php
require_once("fpdf/fpdf.php");
$mypdf = new FPDF();
$mypdf -> AddPage();
$mypdf -> SetTitle("This is for Testing",false);
$mypdf -> SetFont("Arial","B","8");
$mypdf -> SetTextColor(253,12,120);
$mypdf -> SetDrawColor(253,12,120);
$mypdf -> Cell(20,10,"Name",1,0,"L");
$mypdf -> Cell(30,10,"Address",1,0,'');
$mypdf -> Cell(30,10,"Phone Number",1,0,'');
$mypdf -> Cell(20,10,"Email Id",1,0,'');
$mypdf -> Cell(20,10,"State",1,0,'L');
$mypdf -> Cell(20,10,"Gender",1,1,'L');
$mypdf -> Cell(20,10,"Jackson",1,"0","");
$mypdf -> Cell(30,10,"My Adress is Different",1,"0","");
$mypdf -> Cell(30,10,"1234567890",1,"","0",false);
$mypdf -> Cell(20,10,"xxxx1234x@gmail.com",1,"","L",false);
$mypdf -> Cell(20,10,"xxxx xxxxx",1,"","L",false);
$mypdf -> Cell(20,10,"Male",1,"","L",false);
$mypdf -> Output();
?>
```

Comment: How can I write, like this                                             $mypdf -> MultiCell (20,10,"xxxx1234x@gmail.com",1,"","L",false);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MultiCell() instead. [Here is the documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm).

Comment: I meant, you need to use MultiCell() instead of Cell(). But you have to look at the documentation I linked to and you'll see how it's used.

Answer (score 0):

here is your code:

There you can test and use..

```
 <?php
 require('fpdf.php');

 class PDF_MC_Table extends FPDF
  {
  var $widths;
  var $aligns;

   function SetWidths($w)
  {
//Set the array of column widths
$this->widths=$w;
  }

function SetAligns($a)
{
//Set the array of column alignments
$this->aligns=$a;
}

function Row($data)
{
//Calculate the height of the row
$nb=0;
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
    $nb=max($nb,$this->NbLines($this->widths[$i],$data[$i]));
$h=5*$nb;
//Issue a page break first if needed
$this->CheckPageBreak($h);
//Draw the cells of the row
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
{
    $w=$this->widths[$i];
    $a=isset($this->aligns[$i]) ? $this->aligns[$i] : 'L';
    //Save the current position
    $x=$this->GetX();
    $y=$this->GetY();
    //Draw the border
    $this->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h);
    //Print the text
    $this->MultiCell($w,5,$data[$i],0,$a);
    //Put the position to the right of the cell
    $this->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
}
//Go to the next line
$this->Ln($h);
```

}

```
function CheckPageBreak($h)
{
//If the height h would cause an overflow, add a new page immediately
if($this->GetY()+$h>$this->PageBreakTrigger)
    $this->AddPage($this->CurOrientation);
 }

function NbLines($w,$txt)
{
//Computes the number of lines a MultiCell of width w will take
$cw=&$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
if($w==0)
    $w=$this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
$wmax=($w-2*$this->cMargin)*1000/$this->FontSize;
$s=str_replace("\r",'',$txt);
$nb=strlen($s);
if($nb>0 and $s[$nb-1]=="\n")
    $nb--;
$sep=-1;
$i=0;
$j=0;
$l=0;
$nl=1;
while($i<$nb)
{
    $c=$s[$i];
    if($c=="\n")
    {
        $i++;
        $sep=-1;
        $j=$i;
        $l=0;
        $nl++;
        continue;
    }
    if($c==' ')
        $sep=$i;
    $l+=$cw[$c];
    if($l>$wmax)
    {
        if($sep==-1)
        {
            if($i==$j)
                $i++;
        }
        else
            $i=$sep+1;
        $sep=-1;
        $j=$i;
        $l=0;
        $nl++;
    }
    else
        $i++;
}
return $nl;
  }
}
```

?>

thank you

Comment: How can i test Mr Ajay Malhotra?

Comment: 1st i  put my code,page name is example.php, then put your code http://stackoverflow.com/users/2595012/ajay-malhotra?